# Why is this question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Why should [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/75228/41763) be a duplicate? I have explicitly stressed out the diference between the questions. I could agree if the question would be closed for being off topic, but not duplicate.

How can I improve the question to get rid of as much downvotes as posible?

Answer (score 7):

The current question, [Was now really the right moment for Poland to demand concrete reparations from Germany? [duplicate]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/75228/26455), and in its earlier forms, focuses on the the ***Why*** of the earlier question, [What are the pros and cons of demanding 1.3 trillion in reparation from Germany for the Polish government?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/75162/26455).

While the later question may appear to be distinct, it has an answer already present in the earlier question. Specifically, the reason for demanding reparations, and to do so ***now***, is the internal politics of the PiS party.

- From [one answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/75165/26455): For domestic purposes, they are seen as standing up for Polish interests. (See [this Politico article](https://www.politico.eu/article/poland-germany-pay-up/) and [this CNN article](https://us.cnn.com/2022/09/01/europe/poland-germany-wwii-reparations-intl/index.html) on the domestic angle).
- From [another answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/75168/26455): It's about an internal political campaign to rebuild support for the ruling party. The combative stance towards Germany, is often used by this party, PiS, to mobilize its constituency. (Supported by [this source](https://www.swissinfo.ch/eng/poland-puts-its-ww2-losses-at--1.3-trillion--demands-german-reparations/47868566).)

---

[Should a question be marked as a duplicate if there's already an applicable answer on a different question?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4589/26455)

> Questions may be duplicates if they have the same (potential) answers. This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words.

> If understanding why the questions are at all related requires a detailed explanation, the questions aren't duplicates, merely related.

From my perspective, I did not need a *detailed explanation* to understand that the questions were related and that the answer was already given in the earlier question; therefore, the later (your) question is a duplicate.

While I did not pay much attention to either question when asked in September 2022, when it appeared in the Review queue in January 2023, I examined both questions and reached the conclusion of the later question being a duplicate. I can't explain why others closed the question in September, but I suspect it was for similar reasons.

Comment: Although I answered the Q, I concede one can see a substantial degree of overlap with other one. I don't recall if there were any duplicate/close votes cast when I answered, TBH... I see I did notice myself in a comment that there was a related Q...

Comment: There was also a comment by Guntram Blohm that at least partially invalidated the rationale/basis of the Q, i.e. the demand isn't exactly new. That comment was posted about a day after I answered.